# How to order a group of rows by created_at?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sorting, sql-order-by

My visits table looks like this:

| id | name | isp | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jack | Comcast | 2021-03-13 01:00:00 |
| 2 | Jack | Comcast | 2021-03-13 01:01:00 |
| 3 | Tom | Comcast | 2021-03-13 01:02:00 |
| 4 | Jill | Amazon | 2021-03-13 01:03:00 |
| 5 | Jack | Comcast | 2021-03-13 01:50:00 |
| 6 | Jill | Amazon | 2021-03-13 01:06:00 |
| 7 | Jack | Comcast | 2021-03-14 01:00:00 |

I want to group the 'isp' together and then order the group based on the latest created_at of the first row in each group and within in group, order by 'created_at' and 'name'. The resulting table should look like

| id | name | isp | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jack | Comcast | 2021-03-13 01:00:00 |
| 2 | Jack | Comcast | 2021-03-13 01:01:00 |
| 5 | Jack | Comcast | 2021-03-13 01:50:00 |
| 7 | Jack | Comcast | 2021-03-14 01:00:00 |
| 3 | Tom | Comcast | 2021-03-13 01:02:00 |
| 4 | Jill | Amazon | 2021-03-13 01:03:00 |
| 6 | Jill | Amazon | 2021-03-13 01:06:00 |

I have the following code to order by the 'isp' but am stuck on how to order the group of isp based on the first 'created_at'.

```
SELECT * FROM visits
ORDER BY isp
```

Comment: *...on the latest created_at of the first row in each group...* is it the latest or the earliest?

Comment: it is the latest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your version of MySql is 8.0+ use `MAX()` window function in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM visits
ORDER BY MAX(created_at) OVER (PARTITION BY isp) DESC, name, created_at
```

For earlier versions use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT v1.*
FROM visits v1
ORDER BY (SELECT MAX(v2.created_at) FROM visits v2 WHERE v2.isp = v1.isp) DESC, 
         name, created_at
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8b17e6b1fc997ec9cd16f62ecb3ff70f).

| id | name | isp | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jack | Comcast | 2021-03-13 01:00:00 |
| 2 | Jack | Comcast | 2021-03-13 01:01:00 |
| 5 | Jack | Comcast | 2021-03-13 01:50:00 |
| 7 | Jack | Comcast | 2021-03-14 01:00:00 |
| 3 | Tom | Comcast | 2021-03-13 01:02:00 |
| 4 | Jill | Amazon | 2021-03-13 01:03:00 |
| 6 | Jill | Amazon | 2021-03-13 01:06:00 |

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions:

```
order by max(created_at) over (partition by ip) desc,
         ip,
         max(created_at) over (partition by ip, name) desc,
         name,
         created_at desc
```

What are these keys?

- The maximum `created_at` per `ip`.
- Then `ip` so in the event of ties, all the rows for a given `ip` are together.
- The maximum `created_at` for each name for each `ip`.
- Then `name` so the rows for each name are together.
- And finally, `created_at`.